# Overloading == and !=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I was on here earlier to get some information on overloading `*=` and found it very helpful.

I am now trying to overload `==` and `!=`. But I want to make the operator functions **non-member** functions.

Try not to hate all my code blocks - I have included what I believe to be relevant to the issues.

In my source code, I declare the functions:

```
bool operator==(const Statistician&, const Statistician&);
// checks whether Stat1 == Stat2
bool operator!=(const Statistician&, const Statistician&);
// checks whether Stat1 != Stat2
```

Later on I define the functions:

```
// Check if equal
bool operator==(const Statistician& Stat1, const Statistician& Stat2)
{
    if ((Stat1.get_length() == Stat2.get_length()) &&
        (Stat1.get_sum() == Stat2.get_sum()) &&
        (Stat1.get_mean() == Stat2.get_mean()) &&
        (Stat1.get_minimum() == Stat2.get_minimum()) &&
        (Stat1.get_maximum() == Stat2.get_maximum()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// Check if not equal
bool operator!=(const Statistician& Stat1, const Statistician& Stat2)
{
    if ((Stat1.get_length() != Stat2.get_length()) &&
        (Stat1.get_sum() != Stat2.get_sum()) &&
        (Stat1.get_mean() != Stat2.get_mean()) &&
        (Stat1.get_minimum() != Stat2.get_minimum()) &&
        (Stat1.get_maximum() != Stat2.get_maximum()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

In my test driver, I do the actual testing:

```
if (Stat1 == Stat2) { cout << "Equal"; }
if (Stat1 != Stat2) { cout << "Not Equal"; }
```

The rest of my code works fine, and these are again not class member functions.

But when I compile I get these errors:

```
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Statistician' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(507): could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &)'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(512): or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &)'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(517): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t)'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(426): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) throw()'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(434): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) throw()'
      while trying to match the argument list '(Statistician, Statistician)'

error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Statistician' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(522): could be 'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &)'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(527): or       'bool std::operator !=(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &)'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(532): or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t)'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(443): or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) throw()'
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(450): or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) throw()'
      while trying to match the argument list '(Statistician, Statistician)'
```

After much internet research I still don't know what those errors mean.

Comment: Do you declare those operators before you first use them?

Comment: Note that you don't need to do `if (something) return true; else return false;`, you can just say `return something;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your `operator!=` is wrong, it should be

```
if ((Stat1.get_length() != Stat2.get_length()) ||
    (Stat1.get_sum() != Stat2.get_sum()) ||
    (Stat1.get_mean() != Stat2.get_mean()) ||
    (Stat1.get_minimum() != Stat2.get_minimum()) ||
    (Stat1.get_maximum() != Stat2.get_maximum()))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

(note `||` instead of `&&`). Better yet, make that

```
return !(Stat1==Stat2);
```

Now for the error you see: It looks like you forgot to include the header which declares these operators in the translation unit where you are using them. Or, if that is not the case, you need to check which namespaces they are in and if they can be found there from where they are called.

Just to check: If you say "In my source code, I declare the functions:" you mean the header-file (`*.h`) and with "later on" you mean the implementation file (`*.cc`), right?

Comment: +1 Also simplify the definition of `operator==` as `return (Stat1.get_length() == Stat2.get_length()) && ...;`. Personally, I'd make the operators `friend`s and use `std::tie` for implementing the comparisons.

Comment: @Praetorian You are right for experienced developers, but given that the OP is obviously just beginning to learn about operators, let's take one step at a time and not kill her with too much information :)

Comment: So, for that error, I have the function declaration as well as the definition in the same .cpp file. So there shouldn't be an issue with that.

It says there are no operators which take a Statistician as left hand input, and yet when I declare the functions I declare it as

    (Statistician&, Statistician&)

So I'm pretty lost right now.

Comment: @user2824922 You need to put the declaration into a header file and include this header file in the implemention file and in all other files where you want to use the operators. Without this, the compiler won't know in the other files that those operators exist. You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891218) helpful or just google it.

Comment: @DanielFrey, I have a header file which contains my class declarations.

I also have a Source.cpp which contains all the class member definitions, as well as non-member declarations and definitions.

I then have a TestDriver.cpp which is the testing driver.

In my case, I declared and defined the overloaded operators == and != in Source.cpp, so in the same source file.

I then implemented it (Tried calling it) in TestDriver.cpp.

Comment: @user2824922 Put the declaration of the operators in the header, just below the class' declaration.

Comment: @DanielFrey I understand the problem. I was declaring and defining those functions in the same set of source code, but my Test Driver was only able to access my header file, and not the other source file. 

I've fixed the issue and will continue to work on the program. Thanks for your patience!